# Use Apache Tika with the least possible dependency (with Maven)

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, apache-tika

I want to use Apache Tika with as few dependencies as possible because I'm only using the filename on the tika.detect method, so I don't want to include all the unnecessary parsers for me

So what is the dependency for Apache Tika with Maven to use only Tika with a filename and not import all the other unnecessary dependencies for me?

Comment: Do you want container aware detection, or are you happy with just mime magic and filename detection?

Comment: I just wanna use `tika.detect` with a String, which is the filename of a file.

Comment: In that case, `tika-core` should be fine

Comment: But the question is can I use even less dependency than the initial `tika-core` import to lighten the dependency import given my use of tika? @Gagravarr

Comment: Without `tika-core` you won't have any Tika...